mvn dependency:tree show "provided" dependencies
I'm trying to manage a javax -> jakarta migration, and am using mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true heavily.  However one problem is it doesn't show provided dependencies, so it's impossible to find what version of the servlet-api a library has been compiled against.
Is there any way to show this?  I'm already using -Dverbose=true but it still doesn't show them.

I don't have a maven project at hand to test, but it should show provided dependencies. Could it be that the dependency plugin was configured to filter dependencies of a certain scope?
Also it could be that the dependency might be shown under a different scope if there are conflicting declarations.

In a minimal test project, add a dependency to 'commons-fileupload:1.5', but dependency-tree only shows 'commons-io' despite commons-fileupload depending on 'servlet-api:2.4' with scope provided.

Oh you mean on transitive dependencies! Yes, those won't show up as they are optional from the library provider point of view. Take something like hibernate as an example, it probably has 20+ "provided" dependencies that the user of the library might or not want to use (e.g. integration with a cache).
You should be defining those provided dependencies in your project. The Servlet API should be mostly backwards compatible too.
If you still want to go your route, you could write a tiny script that extracts the pom.xml from each dependency and searches for the version of the servlet API.
